# Read in Numbers but Stop at Negative C++

Tags: c++, arrays, input, ifstream

What I am trying to do is read in numbers from a text file (currently called "input"). I am creating two arrays, one for an int number and one for a float number. The maximum number of items in the array is set to 50, however the minimum is 1. The identifier for the program to stop reading numbers is any negative number in the int value.

I'm not sure why, but when I read back my array prints out the numbers, skips the final negative number and then prints out gibberish values for the remaining slots (up to 50).

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
void Read(ifstream &input, int studentID[], float score[])
{
    int curID;
    float curScore;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        input >> curID >> curScore;
        if (curID < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            studentID[i] = curID;
            score[i] = curScore;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you tried to print the array fro 1 to 50 without checking the limit of read element's maximum index. So you have to maintain the total number of elements read and print according to that total count.

Comment: You are right. I just realized this myself. I was printing out 50 values without checking the length of my array. Could you post your response as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code

```
int Read(ifstream & input, int studentID[], float score[])
{
    int curID, i = 0;
    float curScore;
    while (i < 50) {
        input >> curID >> curScore;
        if (curID < 0)
            break;
        else {
            studentID[i] = curID;
            score[i++] = curScore;
        }
    }
    return i;    // This value will be useful while printing the contents
}
```

To avoid gibberish output, only iterate till you read successfully, i.e. the return of `Read(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (curID < 0)
{
    return;
}
```

That's because if you encountered the negative number, your algorithm doesn't store that negative number in `studentID[i]`.

As a result, `studentID` still contains uninitialized values from the first invalid position onwards. With no magic marker present, and no counter passed back either, you can't reconstruct the end of the input.